# JQuery: Transferring Behaviors to Cloned Objects

Tags: jquery, cloning

I'm trying to quickly make copies of a class by binding the clone() method to the doubleclick event. My code, so far is:

```
<style type="text/css">
.draggable { float:left; clear: both; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    copyit = function() {
        $(this).clone().appendTo("body").css('position','absolute').draggable();
    }
    $('.draggable').dblclick(copyit);
    $('.draggable').draggable();
});
</script>

<div class="draggable">Hi There!</div>
<div class="draggable">What's up?</div>
```

Everything works, except I can't get the cloned elements to clone themselves once they are added to the DOM. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the double-click handler with `.live()`:

```
$('.draggable').live("dblclick", copyit);
```

Comment: $('.draggable').live("dblclick", copyit); works perfect. Thanks for your help Pointy and RTP Matt.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are not binding the dblclick event to the new DOM nodes.  In this case you actually have 2 ways you can accomplish this:

1. You can make the dblclick a live (or delegate) event like this:
   $('.draggable').live('dblclick', copyit);
   see:
   http://api.jquery.com/live/
   http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
2. You can make the clone copy the events of the object by passing it true, like this:
   $(this).clone(true).appendTo("body").css('position','absolute').draggable();
   see:
   http://api.jquery.com/clone/